# First order scalar PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Determine the solution of first order scalar partial differential equation.

$$u_t+u_x=u$$
$$u(x,0)={e^{x^2}}$$

$$x\in \mathbb{R}  ,t>0$$

I've tried method of characteristics to make the equations into matrix form 
$$u_x+u_t=u$$ $$u_tdt+u_xdx=du$$but I think it didn't work well. How can i solve this?

Comment: Check if the change I did was correct: I assumed `{e^x}^2` was meant to be $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Consider the equation in light cone coordinates $u=t+x,v=t-x$.

Comment: Another simplification can be found by performing a change of variables to $w = \log(u)$ then the PDE becomes $w_t + w_x = 1$ with initial conditon $w(0,x) = x^2$.

Comment: @Blazej Good idea, but using a different letter than $u$ might be good to avoid confusion with the field $u$.

Comment: Of course, I meant something like $v_{\pm}=t \pm x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plug in $x(t) = y + t$ for some fixed $y \in \mathbb R$, we see by the chain rule, $$\frac{d}{dt}(u(y+t,t)) = u_x(y+t,t) \frac{d}{dt}(y+t) + u_t(y+t,t) = u_x(y+t,t) + u_t(y+t,t).$$ But according to the equation, $u_x+u_t = u$, so $$\frac{d}{dt} u(y+t,t) = u(y+t,t).$$ This yields $$u(y+t,t) = Ce^t.$$ To solve for $C$, plug in $t=0$. This gives $$u(y,0) = C \,\,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, C=e^{y^2}.$$ Then $$u(y+t,t) = e^{y^2+t}.$$ Now using the fact that $y =x-t$, we see $$\boxed{u(x,t) = e^{(x-t)^2 + t}.}$$

I'm not sure exactly how you were taught the method of characteristics because there are several ways to present that sort of material, but for linear equations like: \begin{align*} a(x,t)u_t + b(x,t)u_x &= c(x,t) u \\ u(x,0) &= f(x)\end{align*} if we are looking for characteristics $x=x(s), t= t(s)$ originating from some point $(y,0)$ which is on the boundary where we have data, we ordinarily set \begin{align*} t'(s) &= a(x(s),t(s)), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, t(0) = 0 \\x'(s) &= b(x(s),t(s)), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, x(0) = y \\ 
z'(s) &= c(x(s),t(s))z(s), \,\,\,\,\, z(0) = f(y) \end{align*} where $z(s) = u(x(s),t(s))$. This is a system of ODEs. Once we have solved them, we have $u(x(s),t(s)) = G(s,y)$ for some function $G$. If we can then invert the transformation, we can get $u(x,t) = G(s(x,t),y(x,t))$ which will be our final solution. In your case, we had the particularly simple case that $a(x,t) = b(x,t) = c(x,t) = 1$ which led to the solution I gave.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_x+u_t=u$$
If the method of characteristic is expected, the characteristic equations are :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{u}$$
A first characteristic function is derived from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dt}{1}\quad\to\quad x-t=c_1$

A second characteristic function is derived from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{u}\quad\to\quad u e^{-t}=c_2$

The solution expressed on implicit form is :
$$\Phi \left( (x-t)\:,\: (u e^{-t})\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

From this, $u(x,t)$ can be derived on explicit form :
$$u(x,t)=e^t F(x-t)$$
where $F$ is any derivable function.

With the condition $u(x,0)=e^{x^2}=e^0 F(x-0)\quad\to\quad F(x)=e^{x^2}\quad\to\quad F(x-t)=e^{(x-t)^2}$

$$u(x,t)=e^t e^{(x-t)^2}=e^{(x-t)^2+t}$$